# Apply Filters to WebGL Canvas Itself

Tags: webgl

I am making a game in JavaScript and rendering it to a WebGL canvas.

To give the game some extra spice, I'd like to create filters (or perhaps they're called "Shaders?") to apply directly onto the game's WebGL canvas. More specifically, I'd like to be able to modify the game's brightness, hue, saturation, and give it a bulge effect.

I am totally new to WebGL and would love some guidance!

Comment: If you do have something rendering with WebGL, you do have shaders, find them… then you can edit them.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using the CreateJS library with the WebGL addon

Comment: No idea. I do not know that addon works. However, it must have, somewhere its code the shader programs. If the addon does not expose means to customize the shaders, we would be talking about editing the addon. Alternatively, I suppose, you could execute the calls to replace the shader program (you need to extract the WebGL graphic context), however, the program you load got to be compatible with what they are doing.